# Fix of warning "comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]"

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, warnings

I have problems fixing a GCC warning in one of my template classes (using C++11). I have the following member function in the class:

```
void ThrowInvalidArgumentExceptionIfValueIsLessThanMinimumAllowedValue() const {
  if (static_cast<std::intmax_t>(value_) < kMinimumValue) {
    throw std::invalid_argument{"The specified number " + std::to_string(static_cast<std::intmax_t>(value_)) + " is less than the minimum number " + std::to_string(static_cast<std::intmax_t>(kMinimumValue)) + "."};
  }
}
```

The class has the following template signature (using the CRTP idiom):

```
template <class TClass,
          typename TValue,
          std::intmax_t const kMinimumValue,
          std::intmax_t const kMaximumValue>
```

The following warning is raised for the line with the `if` condition (which makes sense) when using the template signature `<DecimalPercentage, std::uint8_t, 0, 100>`:

```
warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
```

I think the problematic `if` condition may not be compiled `if (std::numeric_limits<TValue>::is_unsigned && kMinimumValue == 0)`, but I have no clue how modify the code in order to avoid the warning.

The following version of the GCC is used:

```
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773]
```

Here is the complete example:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class TClass,
          typename TValue,
          std::intmax_t const kMinimumValue,
          std::intmax_t const kMaximumValue>
struct A {
  A(TValue const kValue) : value_{kValue} {
    // NOOP
  }

  void some_func() const {
    if (static_cast<std::intmax_t>(value_) < kMinimumValue) {
      throw std::runtime_error{"foo"};
    }
  }

  TValue value_;
};

struct B : public A<B, std::uint8_t, 0, 100> {
  B(std::uint8_t const kValue) : A{kValue} {
    // NOOP
  }
};

int main() {
  B temp{0};
  temp.some_func();
}
```

And the command to compile the example: `g++ main.cc -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wtype-limits`

**Edit::** I came across std::enable_if, but I have no idea how to use it. I want to conditionally compile the method, so I think I need something like `std::enable_if<std::is_signed<TValue>::value>::type`. Can someone guide me into the right direction?

Comment: How is about: 
if ( value_   >= kMinimunValue) { do nothing }  
else { throw ...}

Comment: if you want the compilation to fail insert a static_assert. I am not sure what your last statement means

Comment: @nitro2: No that does not help.

Comment: @MagunRa: I tried to clarify it with an example. I cannot check it during compilation, since I do not always know the constructor argument value. Therefore I need that check.

Comment: I still don't get the warning with the example...

Comment: Why would the `static_assert` not work? The constructor argument doesn't matter. The problem is at compile time.

Comment: @imreal: Maybe I misunderstand your suggestion: Can you provide a working example via an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

unsigned int (uint8_t) can never be negative so your check will always fail.

```
static_cast<std::intmax_t>(value_) < kMinimumValue
```

You're casting to an intmax_t but the compiler knows you passed a constant in your main and you're never going to actually use a negative integer value.

Comment: I know that. That check does not make sense for an unsigned data type **if** `kMinimumValue` **is equal** to `0`. My question is how-to **fix** that warning, but keep the logic, since the logic makes sense for all other cases. Your explanation may help others, though, therefore I upvoted it.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a signed kValue? ie, int8_t or int32_t?

Comment: I could use a signed data type in the example to avoid the warning, but that doesn't anwser my question. And since Is use that template class inserialization code, the underlying data type does matter. Therefore changing the data type isn't a solution for me.